# How do you detect a click in a cell of a grid and change its color?

Tags: python, pygame, grid

Quite new to python and trying to re-create a game I played at school. for this game, I need to randomly spawn these bombs that reduce your bank account to zero if hit and change the colour of the bomb square of the square to red (while safe ones go green).
The issues I'm having are:

- I want to change the colour of a bomb square red, they don't do this though, they just stay white, however, the safe ones do go green
- also for the co-ordinates of the bomb, I want to make sure none of those are equal, I want to make it so it re-rolls the duplicate one

Any help with either of those would be greatly appreciated

```
#--------------------------------Pirate Game-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#initilising
import pygame
import random
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
 

width = 20
height = 20
margin = 5#gap between 

current = 0
bank = 0
turnnumber = 0

grid = []
for row in range(10):
    # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
    # in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0) 
 

pygame.init()
GameR = [600,600]
gameD = pygame.display.set_mode(GameR)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pirate Game")
 
done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#FUNCTIONS
def bombs():
    for i in range(5):
        row = random.randrange(10)
        column = random.randrange(10)
        grid[row][column] = 2
        print(row,column)



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#MAIN LOOP:

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bombs()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print("Dont Press that")
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = pos[0] // (width + margin)
            row = pos[1] // (height + margin)
            if grid[row][column] == 2:
                print('Boom')
            if grid[row][column] != 2:
                grid[row][column] = 1
                print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

                
    gameD.fill(black)
 
    #Draw the grid
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(10):
            color = white
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = green
            elif grid[row][column] == 2:
                colour = red
            pygame.draw.rect(gameD,
                             color,
                             [(margin +
                               width) * column + margin,
                              (margin + height) * row + margin,
                              width,
                              height])
 
    
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
 
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a typo: `color = red` rather than `colour = red`.

Anyway you've to change your game logic. Use the values 0 and 2 for cells which are not clicked and the values 1 and 3 for cells that have been clicked. Initialize all fields of the grid by 0. Put random bombs on the grid by assigning 2 to random cells.
When a cell with the value 0 is clicked, then change its value to 1. When a cell with a bomb (value 2) is clicked then change it to 3:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        # [...]

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = event.pos[0] // (width + margin)
            row = event.pos[1] // (height + margin)
            if grid[row][column] == 2:
                print('Boom')
                grid[row][column] = 3
            if grid[row][column] == 0:
                grid[row][column] = 1
                print("Click ", event.pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)
```

When you draw the grid, then all the cells have to be drawn white. Except a cell has the value 1. In this case it's color is green. If a cell has the value 3, it's color is red:

```py
while not done:
    # [...]

    #Draw the grid
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(10):
            color = white
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = green
            elif grid[row][column] == 3:
                color = red
            cell_rect = ((margin + width) * column + margin, (margin + height) * row + margin, width, height)
            pygame.draw.rect(gameD, color, cell_rect)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
#initilising
import pygame
import random
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
 
width = 20
height = 20
margin = 5#gap between 

current = 0
bank = 0
turnnumber = 0

grid = []
for row in range(10):
    # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
    # in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0) 
 
pygame.init()
GameR = [600,600]
gameD = pygame.display.set_mode(GameR)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pirate Game")
 
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#FUNCTIONS
def bombs():
    for i in range(5):
        row = random.randrange(10)
        column = random.randrange(10)
        grid[row][column] = 2
        print(row,column)

bombs()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#MAIN LOOP:

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bombs()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print("Dont Press that")
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column = event.pos[0] // (width + margin)
            row = event.pos[1] // (height + margin)
            if grid[row][column] == 2:
                print('Boom')
                grid[row][column] = 3
            if grid[row][column] == 0:
                grid[row][column] = 1
                print("Click ", event.pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)
           
    gameD.fill(black)
 
    #Draw the grid
    for row in range(10):
        for column in range(10):
            color = white
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = green
            elif grid[row][column] == 3:
                color = red
            cell_rect = ((margin + width) * column + margin, (margin + height) * row + margin, width, height)
            pygame.draw.rect(gameD, color, cell_rect)
 
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
 
pygame.quit()
```